# circuitikz: setting color using \pgfmathparse

Tags: color, circuitikz, pgfmathparse

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{circuitikz} \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,shapes,decorations.markings} \begin{document} 
\begin{circuitikz} [american currents]  
\foreach \x in {1,2,3} {    
\def\myr{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,2))}\pgfmathresult}   
  \draw (\x,0) [nos=\myr, color={rgb:red,1; blue,0}] to (\x,1); % <---
} 
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

The above code produces the attached image. I would like the switch 0 to be in blue. Changing the highlighted line to

```
\draw (\x,0) [nos=\myr, color={rgb:red,\myr; blue,1-\myr}] to (\x,1);
```

cause texmaker 5.0.3 to crash on osx. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it has to do with the `1-\myr` used in the coloring. One solution is to deriving both the red and blue with `\pgfmathparse`. By using this you need to expand `\pgfmathresult` when defining the colors, hence the `\xdef` instead of `\def`. I have also put the `\pgfmathparse` outside the definition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,shapes,decorations.markings} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{circuitikz} [american currents]  
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3} {    
    \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,2))}\xdef\myr{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{int(1-mod(\x,2))}\xdef\myb{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (\x,0) [nos=\myr, color={rgb:red,\myr; blue,\myb}] to (\x,1);
  } 
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, +1. Although I find `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myr}{int(mod(\x,2))}` easier to grasp...

Comment: Thanks. That has solved the problem!